# 2 click events on one element, only one needs to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have 2 click events on one element (button). The first is a default function to do some general checks (which are be done on general steps in my proces) and the second one is a specific check for that specific step in my proces.

All the steps in my proces have a next button to go to the next step (next page), but if a step need specific checks (field validation), I give the `<div>` around it an extra class, so I can handle it with jQuery.

**Default step next button**

HTML:

```
<div>
   <a class="next-button" href="http://www.example.com/to-next-step/">Next step</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.next-button').click(function() {
   // Default checks
});
```

**Specific step next button**

HTML:

```
<div class="specific-step">
   <a class="next-button" href="http://www.example.com/to-next-step/">Next step</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.specific-step .next-button').click(function() {
   // Specific checks
});
```

When I click the button on a step with an extra class around it, both functions are running. Is it possible to only run the "specific next button function" then?

Comment: If you have control over the order the handlers are added, I have added a one-line alternative to my answer (using http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test if the parent has the specific step, from inside the single generic click handler attached to all `.next-button`:

```
$('.next-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('specific-step')){
         performSpecificStep();
    }
    else{
        // Do standard stuff
    }
});
```

An alternative is to use [`e.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/), but this solution requires your "specific" handlers to be attached *first* as they execute in the order they are attached:

e.g.

```
$('.specific-step .next-button').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$('.next-button').click(function (e) {
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nb6thezu/

Comment: Same thing I was getting at just testing the class instead, I sense you'll get the votes. People lurve the sexy code layout. Have a vote.

Comment: But wouldn't it still work, since .specific-step still IS the parent?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Sorry, super ugly.

Comment: @M K: Ah, the revenge down-vote. This is really simple, obvious and *works* :)

Comment: It's funny since now your only vote is from myself @TrueBlueAussie hehe. Love how more people are still posting too "I can has rep?"

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, it was pretty much Psuedocode anyway, I'll just remove the answer.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for your answer. It looks like it works as in your fiddle, but I have tried it and it doesn't work. Maybe because in my example the class is on the direct parent, and in my project not.. My fault.

Comment: @Robbert: change `.parent()` to `.closest(someselector)` where `someselector` matches the ancestor with the optional class on it. If you provide a sample of the real HTML I will adjust the answer to match

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie No I didn't talk about your first answer, but about your edit.

Comment: @Robbert: I would need to see the actual HTML to improve on  my suggestion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to the specific elements (e.g. specific-step)

**Default Button**

```
<a class="next-button" href="http://www.example.com/to-next-step/">Next step</a>
```

**Specific Button**

```
<a class="next-button specific-step" href="http://www.example.com/to-next-step/">Next step</a>
```

And your jquery:

```
$('.next-button').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('specific-step')){
         performSpecificStep();
    }else{
      // do normal stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Just test against the parent within one event, simpler ^^

Comment: @Callum, no need to include the parent in it at all

Comment: OP might need parent for styling bro ^^

Answer (score 0):

Since you want entirely separate functionality for each type of link, I would identify each type of link with a distinct class.

`<a class="next-button default-step" ...
<a class="next-button specific-step" ...`

Keep your CSS styles in `next-button`, then attach event handlers to `default-step` and `specific-step`.

Then you can avoid:

1. Hard coding CSS classnames into your event handlers
2. Embedding different functions into a single function using `if ... else`

My gut says this design will be easier to change in future.

edit: If only one of these buttons is ever present on a page, perhaps using an ID instead of a class makes more sense. Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. the ">" makes sure you bind the click function to the child of "specific-step".

```
$('.specific-step > .next-button').click(function() {
   // Specific checks
});
```

Comment: The other `.next-button` selector will still fire the other event.

Comment: This is not useful as the first click event would still run.